# What kinds of memory does an Android device have?

Tags: internal-storage, ram

What kind/types of memory (or data storage devices) does and android device have, and what information is stored in that type of memory?

I know of:

- Internal memory
- RAM Memory
- ROM Memory
- Storage card / SD/Card

Answer (score 5):

Android devices are very similar to computers, they consist of a BIOS (Basic Input Output System), an OS (Operating System) and then Applications and Data.

- The BIOS would be stored in EEPROM (Electrically Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory), or rather a sub-type called Flash Memory. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory))
- When the BIOS loads the OS then it is moved into RAM Memory. RAM memory stores all currently running applications (including the OS). ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM))
- The Operating System software, and application software are stored in storage; which is usually an internal SD card, or SD card like storage. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital))

  - You can have additional storage, such as an external SD card.

So you would have

- EEPROM (Flash Memory)
- RAM (System Memory)
- SD Card (Storage)